# sudo pecl command not found

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, sudo

I'm using ubuntu 12.04

I installed php pear using this command

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

I got this results

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-pear is already the newest version.
php5-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Now when I use this command

```
sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.3
```

I'm getting this error

```
sudo: pecl: command not found
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?
Thankyou

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f php-pear php5-dev` could possibly do it

Comment: I still got the same message.. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 8):

Fire up a terminal and use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
```

Comment: I've done all the steps. But nothing works. I still getting that same message. `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.

I completely remove old packages using

```
sudo apt-get purge php-pear
```

Then installed pear using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -f php-pear php5-dev
```

Now it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but still valid. Im using php 7.4 with Ubuntu 20.04 but none of the above works for me

instead for php7.4 I executed the following commands at my terminal

```
sudo apt install php-dev php-pear
```

then you can run:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

credit goes to https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php#125027

Answer (score 0):

check your enviroment variable. `/etc/environment`. it should be like that `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Answer (score 0):

i added the plugin `sudo apt install php-dev php-pear` before using `sudo pecl install mongodb`.

here is the article
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php#125027